# Moving mail from permanently offline account's inbox (macOS Mail.app)?

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

I have an old, no longer accessible IMAP account (or two) with mail that I need off of it. I can access the mail in this defunct account (cached/local copies now on my machine); but my attempts to move the emails in the inbox, or even copy them, fail. Is there some other way to export them to a mailbox on my hard drive (within Mail.app)?

Comment: What happens when you put the account offline? Can you then see your messages?  Try the archive when you are offline.

Comment: You might review this Q-and-A: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312942/recovering-emails-from-defunct-imap-account?rq=1 which seems to address the same issue, and offers a solution.

Comment: @historystamp, I can currently see the messages... I simply want to copy or move them out of the mailbox, so that I can then kill the accounts.

Comment: @David, thanks so much! I'm gonna check this out!

Comment: Have you tried mail > mailboxes > export?